# Open/Upload file Dialogue - make file preview larger

Tags: google-chrome, thumbnails

I work in Chrome a lot and do a lot of meme type image uploads from Chrome for a Page that I admin. Frequently, I can't read the text on the image previews I'm looking at in the upload dialogue box.

As I tend to pick the images I'm going to upload from the dialogue box, this is a serious hurdle for me. Obviously I'd like to change that, maybe make the thumbnail/preview area twice the size so that visibility is better. How do I do that?

[image: screenshot of open dialogue with preview area highlight for desired expansion]

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Can you maybe provide an example with screenshot(s)?

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: Afaik you can usually drag files from the file manager of your choice (Nautilus, Nemo, Dolphin…) into file upload areas of websites. It definitely works for your standard `Browse…` file picker in plain HTML forms. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.. it's quite ridiculous, it makes finding the right image incredibly painful.

In the regular Nautilus window you can tweak the icon size well enough, but in the Open File dialog (File selector) you only get 'nearly invisible'.  Why can't you switch to a grid layout here with larger icons sizes?

(And then if the drive happens to be a network drive you don't get any preview at all.)

[image: Open File dialog with ridiculously small thumbnail previews]